# JQuery Header not displaying in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a table with JQuery and everything seems to work, except I can't get the header to show up. I'm declaring the header, appending to the table, then appending the column names to the header. The rest of the table displays exactly how I want it to. I didn't think it should matter what order I do this in. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('[attr="searchResultsJson"]').length)
  {
    $('.comment-section').hide();
    $('#InboxDetailsDrawer').hide();

    $('.approval-outer-wrap').prepend(drawTable());
  }
});

function drawTable(){
  var table = $('<table id="search-results" />');

  var header = $('<thead />');
  table.append(header);

  header.append = $('<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Data Pulse ID</th><th>Laserfiche ID</th></tr>');

  var body = $('<tbody />');
  table.append(body);

  var json = $('[attr="searchResultsJson"] [type="text"]').text();
  console.log(json);

  var searchResults = JSON.parse(json);

  for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++)
  {
    body.append('<tr>'+
                `<td>${searchResults[i].patientFirstName}</td>` +
                `<td>${searchResults[i].patientLastName}</td>` +
                `<td>${searchResults[i].patientDateOfBirth}</td>` +
                `<td>${searchResults[i].patientDataPulseID}</td>` +
                `<td>${searchResults[i].patientLaserFicheID}</td>` +
                '</tr>')
  }

  return table;
}
```

Comment: `attr="searchResultsJson"` seems like an invalid HTML5 attribute. Use valid `data-*` attributes.

Comment: The rest of the table works fine. I'm using this in LaserFiche forms so I'm pulling data from a LF workflow. Would that affect the header?

Comment: `header.append = ` is not valid jQuery, shoujld be `.append()`

Comment: Also: `[type="text"]').text()` is wrong. `type="text"` looks like you have an input. And input has `Element.value` not `Element.textContent` (AKA .text() in jQuery). Therefore you're again using wrong attributes (perhaps on a textarea? Anyways, use `.val()`. If it's a DIV, than `type="text"` is not a valid DIV attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append()` is a function and you need to pass the content as an argument against `append =` when appending the header content. Please find the corrected code below.

```js
$(document).ready(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
  var table = $('<table id="search-results">');

  var header = $('<thead>');
  table.append(header);

  header.append('<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Data Pulse ID</th><th>Laserfiche ID</th></tr>');

  var body = $('<tbody>');
  table.append(body);

  $('body').append(table);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I'll mark your answer correct once the time limit allows me to.